# Linux serial port driver suspend resume

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to turn ON/OFF some port bits on ttyS2 suspend/resume scenario but from driver code it is difficult to find code stub where I can check for ttyS2 and set/unset bits on suspend/resume.

Can anyone point be specific location or logic where i can decode port name and do specific action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can look for driver name using "kobject_name" as registered by device driver. For serial driver we get tty instance number on specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in user space.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: It was an answer, but I was trying to be polite. Edited back to the original.